# jQuery select elements when attribute is contained in attribute list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox, label, jquery-attributes

Better explain with an example (i'm very new to jQuery, sorry in advance):

```
// Selector for checkboxes not checked
var checkboxes = "input:checkbox:not(:checked)";

// Selector for labels relative to checkboxes not checked
var labels = "label[for=" + $(checkboxes).attr("id") + "]";

$(checkboxes + ", " + labels]).FadeTo("slow", 0.45);
```

This works for checkboxes but nor for labels (strangely, only one label gets selected).

Question are: how can i select "attached" labels? And, how `.attr("name")` actually works when more than one element is selected (returns an array, a concatenated list, or... what?).

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: You can basically fade the container which has checkbox and label both.

Comment: @BoltClock: i use mvc because i don't know in advance how the view should be adapted to suite client needs. So HTML structure can easily change, a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function(){
    $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').add(this).fadeTo('slow',0.45);
});
```

Comment: Well I suppose this would be it. If it's not necessary to chain stuff, don't chain stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

> (strangely, only one label gets selected)

> And, how `.attr("name")` actually works when more than one element is selected (returns an array, a concatenated list, or... what?).

Calling `.attr()` on a set of elements only returns the attribute value for the first element. So in your case, the label for the first checkbox is selected.

You can always create a bunch of selector strings dynamically by looping, but that's not very efficient. If your labels and checkboxes are in a predictable HTML structure you can use that to your advantage instead, with jQuery's [traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing).

Comment: I'd like not to rely on css selectors, and i don't know where elements will be placed in the three...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Selector for checkboxes not checked
var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)'), 
    selector = [];

checkboxes.each(function(){
  selector.push('[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
});

// Selector for labels relative to checkboxes not checked
var labels = $('label:' + selector.join());
```

I guess that should be sufficient.

Comment: According to the docs, "selector matches the test string against each word in the attribute value, where a 'word' is defined as a string delimited by whitespace. The selector matches if the test string is exactly equal to any of the words."

and afaik element ID can't contain whitespace :)

Comment: You have it backwards. Think of `[class~="foo"]` as the equivalent of `.foo` for selecting `<div class="foo bar"></div>` - the whitespace is in the HTML attribute rather than the selector.

Comment: Guess you're right, I actually went and test it :) 
However, I fixed the answer a bit, this time it's tested and working.